# How to reverse order in *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular

Please help user order module in *ngFor directive.

I install "ngx-order-pipe": "^1.0.2", and use it in app.module.ts:

```
import { OrderModule } from 'ngx-order-pipe';
...
..

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    OrderModule,
    ...
    ..
  ],
  providers: [AgendaService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My template:

```
<div class="line" *ngFor="let line of agenda | orderBy:'order'; let iLine = index">
  <div class="left">
    {{ line.start.trim() }} - {{ line.end.trim() }}  
    = {{line.order}} 
  </div>       
</div>
```

It worked (lines sorted ascending). But i need lines sorted descending.

I try follow:

```
<div class="line" *ngFor="let line of agenda | orderBy:'-order'; let iLine = index">
    .....    
</div>
```

But it not worked.

[GITHUB is here](https://github.com/zlodiak/ng4_agenda)

Comment: How did it not work? What did you expect to happen? What id actually happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ngx-order-pipe` has this syntax:

`{{ collection | orderBy: expression : reverse }}`

So to use descending order, you need to use second parameter:

`*ngFor="let line of agenda | orderBy:'order':true; let iLine = index"`

More about this on their github:

https://github.com/VadimDez/ngx-order-pipe